# How to preview image or video when selecting a file

Tags: javascript, html

So I've managed the image preview where users can now select a file and preview it before uploading:

makeapost.php

```
   <input type="text" id="thetitle" name="title" placeholder="Title">
    <input type="text" id="imagepath" name="imagepath" hidden>
    <input type="file" name="file" onchange="readURL(this)">
    <img src="" id="img"> <br>
    <video width="320" height="240" style="display:none" controls autoplay>
    <source src="" id="forvideo">
    </video>
```

main.js

```
function readURL(input) {
  if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
    
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function (e) { 
      document.querySelector("#img").setAttribute("src",e.target.result);
    };

    reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]); 
  }
  
}
```

However, clearly it doesnt work with videos and I would like to know how I could preview both images and videos from one input, without having to seperate them both. Any tips? Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please fix your tags. You are using JavaScript, not Java. [These are two separate languages](https://www.java.com/en/download/help/java_javascript.html). Please also tell us what you have tried, and also maybe put it in a preview code instead of 2 normal codes. This will help us diagnose your problem. Read - https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex to detect a file type and then add extra logic for video loading.

```js
function readURL(input) {
  //hide video frame initially
  var videoSource = document.querySelector("#forvideo");
  videoSource.parentNode.style.display = "none";
  if (input.files && input.files[0]) {

var reader = new FileReader();
reader.onload = function(e) {
  //regex to check file type
  var match = reader.result.match(/^data:([^/]+)\/([^;]+);/) || [];
  var type = match[1];

  //if file type is a video, we load video and change display style
  if (type === "video") {
    videoSource.src = URL.createObjectURL(input.files[0]);
    videoSource.parentNode.load();
    videoSource.parentNode.style.display = "block";
  }
  
  //your original logic for loading image
  if (type === "image") {
    document.querySelector("#img").setAttribute("src", e.target.result);
  }
};
reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
  }
}
```

```html
   <input type="text" id="thetitle" name="title" placeholder="Title">
   <input type="text" id="imagepath" name="imagepath" hidden>
   <input type="file" name="file" onchange="readURL(this)">
   <img src="" id="img"> <br>
   <video width="320" height="240" style="display:none" controls autoplay>
     <source src="" id="forvideo">
   </video>
```

Comment: This code doesn't seem to work at all, doesnt load pictures nor videos

Comment: I just modified my code a little bit. You can verify it again. :D @Hamodicoolguy